# Adding to datetime in php

Tags: php, datetime

If i have:

```
if($date>=$start_interval...){

//Some code

}
```

Where both $date (current date) and $start_interval are both in datetime format - like YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.  What do i need to do to add an hour (or 60 minutes) to $start_interval?

So the if statement would be - if($date>=$start_interval (+hour)) - in other words if its more than an hour later do something.  How would you do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). It makes working with dates easy.

```
$now = new DateTime();

$start_interval = new DateTime('2012-12-14 00:00:00');
$start_interval->modify('+1 hour');

if ($now >= $start_interval)
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Will this work if i am retrieving $start_interval from mysql?

Comment: Yes. You can pass it a value from the DB as long as it is in an acceptable format. MySQL's native datetime format is perfect to use.

Comment: So, in which case, am i right in thinking the second line of your suggestion is redundant?  I'm pretty new to php that's all.

Comment: It's just a generic example to point you in the right direction. Your implementation may be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (strtotime($date) >= strtotime('+1 hour', strtotime($start_interval)) {

//Some code

}
```

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php